# Add Active Class to a Navigation Menu Based on URL javascript - Works only when alert is given

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a website containing about 8/10 webpages. I have implemented a common header and footer using javascript which is working fine. The next step was to add a active class to the navigation menu which I read is possible either through javascript or jquery. I stumbled upon a article which had both the jquery as well as the javascript method. [How to Add Active Class to a Navigation Menu Based on URL](http://webdesignerhut.com/active-class-navigation-menu/)

The jquery method seems to be working fine for me only when I add an alert
statement in between.

```
 $(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     alert(pgurl); //Works fine if this statement is included
     $("#nav ul li a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
});
```

I did refer a few more articles and looks like most of them use the same method more or less. Any suggestion?

Comment: it should work can you please try $(function() {
  $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
});  once

Comment: Please try and let me know it this works for you

Comment: No, this did not work for me, although this looks like a clean and simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some `timeout`, may be your view is not ready for sometime, try following code :-

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){

        var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

        $("#nav ul li a").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });

    }, 5000);
});
```

It may help you.