# How to add Active class based on page URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, url, addition

Sorry if this has been addressed before, but I'm very new to JS.
I'm using an example I've found here [Add Active Class to a Navigation Menu Based on URL javascript - Works only when alert is given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447928/add-active-class-to-a-navigation-menu-based-on-url-javascript-works-only-when)
My altered JS is here:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        console.log(pgurl);

        $(".mega_menu ul li a").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

The console log is producing what appears to be the correct link however the active class is not being applied to the required class, I've included screenshots to hopefully help.[console log displaying URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue838.jpg), [NAV elements that ACTIVE class should be applied to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxLVV.jpg).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The issue seems to be with the .each loop. Especially the this keyword. Add console log inside there and check the value of this.

Comment: Hi @SagarAgrawal , thanks but I'm not sure exactly what you mean, are you able to alter my code so I understand and then I'm happy to test

Comment: can you check the pgurl value? it seems the problem is window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1) your logic to extract current url. use pathname instead

Answer (score 0):

Except pgurl, there is no issue with your code.

```
$(function() {
setTimeout(function(){

 //   var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

    var pgurl = window.location.pathname.replace("/","") + window.location.search; //replace first "/" and make it empty

    $("#nav ul li a").each(function(){
          var _this = this;
         //your condition fails here, can you check your pgurl has this value?
         //old - if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )  
       // pgurl - hardcoded 'merchandise2.asp?Merchandise_Group1_ID=8' to run the code successfully
        if($(_this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(_this).attr("href") == '' ) {
           $(_this).addClass("active"); 
           console.log(_this)
        }
    });

}, 50); });
```

Please note: you should not use getting and extracting the URL like this 
window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

instead refer the easiest way to get url details 
https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-get-current-url-in-javascript.html

Comment: Hi @Kannan G , thanks for the response, would the alteration you've made only add the class when the link matched "merchandise2.asp?Merchandise_Group1_ID=8" explicitly. The idea was to have the current page URL obtained, trim off the front part [i.e. www.website.com.au/] and then apply the class "active" if the part of the site left in this instance "merchandise2.asp?Merchandise_Group1_ID=8", however this could change if you were in another section of the menu, [ for example the next menu item has the link "merchandise2.asp?Merchandise_Group1_ID=24".

Comment: @adouglas1880 can you please check now, i updated my code block

Comment: this returned the full URL not the section on the end [i.e. "domain name"/merchandise2.asp] not the required "merchandise2.asp?Merchandise_Group1_ID=8"

Comment: sorry for the delay, window.location.search to get the query param @adouglas1880

Answer (score 0):

I thank everyone for your help. Below is the code that functions, and it's obvious that I have a way to go, in my understanding of JS:

```
        $(function() {
            setTimeout(function(){

                var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

                console.log(pgurl)

                $("ul.mega_menu li a.mega_menu_with_ul").each(function(){
                      var _this = this;
                      console.log(_this)
                    //your condition fails here, can you check your pgurl has this value?
                    //old - if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )  
                    // pgurl - hardcoded 'merchandise2.asp?Merchandise_Group1_ID=8' to run the code successfully
                    if($(_this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(_this).attr("href") == '' ) {
                        $(_this).addClass("active"); 
                        console.log(_this)
                    }
            });

        }, 50); });
```

I believe I was running into an issue in both the way the CSS calls were structured and my understanding of how specific I needed to be to address the correct element with Javascript.